# Finding $f(8)$ given series for the nth derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> A function $f$ has the value $-1$ in $x = 0$. Furthermore, the nth derivative of $f$ in $x = 0$ is given by $$f^n(0) = 11\frac{n!}{10^n}$$ for $n \ge 1$. It is given that $f$ is equal to its Maclaurin series on the interval $(-10,10)$. What is $f(8)$?

Not sure where to begin on this one. Im not sure if you have to find the Maclaurin series for the function they're describing, or if there is some simpler way to do this.

Comment: You've been given all you need to construct the Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=f(0)+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}=-1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{11 x^n}{10^n}=-1-\frac{11 x}{x-10}=\frac{2 (5-6 x)}{x-10}$$
$f(8)=43$

Hope this helps